# REST API and slect where in list

Tags: php, rest, api

I am developping a REST API in php with json. I developped a GET method that execute this query: `SELECT mac FROM pc_list where id IN (1,2,3)`. This is my method in pc_list.php file and .htaccess file.

```
function get_mac_by_id($id=0){
global $connection;
$query="SELECT id FROM pc_list";
if($id!=0){
$query.="WHERE id IN (".$id.")";
 }
$result=mysqli_query($connection,$query);
if(mysqli_num_rows($result)­ >0){
$response=array();
while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
 {
$response=['macs'][]=$row;
}
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($response);
}
}
```

.htaccess file:

```
 RewriteEngine On
ReriteRule ^pc_list/?$ pc_list.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^pc_list/([0-9]+)/?$ pc_list.php?id=$1 [QSA,NC,L]
```

I executed this url localhost/api/REST/pc_list/1,2 I get this error: `The requested URL /api/REST/pc_list/1,2 was not found on this server`, When I execute this one I get a result localhost/api/REST/pc_list/1

What I know that according to my .htaccess file the comma is considered as a redirection not a character. I want to find a way to make it work.

Comment: Could you pass the IDs to the GET endpoint as a query parameter instead of a path parameter? `.../pc_list?ids=1,2 &otherqueryparam=val`

Answer (score 0):

The reason of the error it that the regex `^pc_list/([0-9]+)/?$` for the RewriteRule does not allow comma's. Also you want to ensure you escape the $id variable (of type string) before inserting it in the $query variable.

I would change the regex from `^pc_list/([0-9]+)/?$` to `^pc_list/([0-9,]+)/?$` or even `^pc_list/([^/]+)/?$` and then do proper input parsing and validation in PHP.